# Postgresql | Database with OID doesn't exist

Tags: postgresql

So, how it started, DB started throwing errors about "database with OID 1"

```
2014-02-07 22:54:46.561 GET >ERROR:  database is not accepting commands to avoid wraparound data loss in database with OID 1
2014-02-07 22:54:46.561 GET >HINT:  Stop the postmaster and use a standalone backend to vacuum that database.
        You might also need to commit or roll back old prepared transactions.
```

OK, let's find DB with OID = 1:

```
backend> select oid,datname from pg_database where oid=1
         1: oid (typeid = 26, len = 4, typmod = -1, byval = t)
         2: datname     (typeid = 19, len = 64, typmod = -1, byval = f)
        ----
backend>
```

result = **nothing**. I've checked all DB's I've got and all of them have unique OID, none with value of "1".

## Configuration

### Software:

CentOS 6 x86_64 (always fresh updates), postgresql 9.3.2 / RPM's from postgresql.org. fsync=on, autovacuum=on, rest is default (commented).

### Block layers:

SAS Disks (write cache off) -> Dell Perc RAID (RAID 10, battery backed write cache) -> LVM LV for pgsql -> ext4 (defaults).
No errors reported on block level by OS or HW RAID consistency check, no power failures (never occured).

## DB with OID=1

By default, when running initdb, postgres creates database with template0 and template1. DB OID for template1 = 1, but in my case for some reason - it's not.

Comment: If you don't have an extremely fresh backup, stop the DB and back it up, at the file system level, before continuing. You're probably OK at this point, but a backup is still a really good thing to have right now. This looks extremely suspicious; a DB should never be able to have oid=1, so I really suspect you've got some DB corruption going on here.

Comment: Please show: your exact PostgreSQL version, your OS, relevant parts of your `postgresql.conf` - in particular the autovacuum parameters and the `fsync` parameter. Look in the log files for prior messages about wraparound and show any you find. Check `dmesg` for I/O errors, and the kernel logs. Describe any recent crashes, power losses or unexpected restarts (pg doesn't mind these IF your server's storage system works OK).

Comment: Describe your server and storage subsystem (disk type/configuration, direct attached, using internal HBA, SAN; write-back or write-through cache, LVM, `md`, filesystem type, filesystem mount options, etc).

Comment: Also, try starting PostgreSQL with use of system indexes disabled, and run your query for the DB with oid 1 again. See the docs for how to start it.

Comment: updated accordingly

Comment: OK, and if you run the same query with a standalone backend using the flags `-P -F i` ? (see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-postgres.html) . Oh, and what's the output of `pg_controldata /path/to/database/directory`  and of `select oid, datname, datfrozenxid, datminmxid FROM pg_catalog.pg_database`?

Comment: thx, will try with disabled indexes and update the question.
Actually, I've solved the problem with tricky workaround, but I've saved the base files to reproduce the problem, because it's really annoying.

Comment: It's also _worrying_ - in the absence of known hardware or software failures, there's the potential of a Pg bug here. So please do retain an unmodified copy of the datadir.

Comment: @GioMac how did you work around it?

Comment: @dezso dump, initdb, restore :)